# How to ensure search engines index specific version of site

Tags: seo

I am just starting to work on my first responsive site and am realizing some SEO things may fit on the front page of our site may not fit 'naturally' on the front page of the mobile version.

Is there anyway to ensure search engines see the full-size site?

Once complicating matter is that I am designing the site 'mobile first'. So the site does not default to full-size, it defaults to mobile sizes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO, not a specific programming question.

Comment: Well, SEO is one of the possible tags.

Comment: The SEO tag on StackOverflow is for programming questions such as how to implement a specific URL format.   SEO questions such as this that are not programming related are generally moved to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well, looking at [the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo?sort=newest&pagesize=50), you'll see that most of the recent questions are "on hold", "closed" or "migrated". I imagine those that weren't closed are either programming related (and are thus likely appropriate) or slipped through the cracks. Similarly, for example, there's a [tag:windows] tag, but non-programming Windows questions aren't within StackOverflow's scope (and likely belong on [su]).

Comment: You say tamatoe I say tomato. 'Is there anyway to ensure search engines see the full-size site?' is a programming question. Any solution will required code in HTML, CSS, PHP or Javascript. Therefore it is a 'specific programming question'. Perhaps the need is beyond your scope of experience in this type of programming so it's intent may be elusive to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you deliver the same content to the end user regardless of device, and just show/hide or reformat based upon a media query, it really doesn’t matter. Google will still get the full content of the page so will index all of your content. What is visible in the viewport isn’t really significant to Google.
Google will, however, understand the use of media queries and give you some additional SEO benefits as a result. Google favours responsive design over separate sites/mobile specific pages. Responsive design also helps improve the indexing efficiency of the Googlebot.

One thing they do advise is not to block access to any of your ‘external’ resources (css, js, images etc)

[Plenty of good information here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details)

Comment: Thanks. I guess the issue is that on our full-size page, we have a <div> based pop-up that has a list of countries and cities available. This is important for our SEO because this list is dynamic and changes often. This list is quite big and would not really be able to work the same way in a mobile design, so it will need to be on second page. If that is the only option, that is fine, but we would rather it is on the first page.

Comment: Thanks for your response LDJ. I am going to accept it now as I believe my question is about to be closed. Your link was helpful.